# SAS encoding problem in output file

Tags: encoding, sas

I met a weird problem when outputing contents in data set into external file.

```
    data test (encoding=utf8);
        set test1;
        file "U:\Projects\...\test.txt" encoding='utf-8' mod;
        put
    /   '       <termEntry id="' _N_ +(-1) '">'
    /   '         <note type="TS_Status">' status '</note>'
    /   '         <note type="TS_Remark">' message_from_admin '</note>'
.....
....
;
run;
```

Encoding of dataset test1 is utf-8.

The problem is encoding of output file test.txt varies with the input contents!!E.g.

When 100 lines are input, it's in utf-8; when 10 lines are input, it's in ANSI.

The same problem occurs even if I remove both\either **encoding= options** after **data statement** and **file statement**

So I'd like to know

1. Why this happens and how to control the encoding accurately?
2. How encoding= options in both locations make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there, no one has any answers?

Comment: @mj - the encoding option on the file statement should be the only thing that would affect the encoding of the test.txt file. Are you certain you are getting ANSI encoding with fewer than 10 lines input (if so, please explain how you determined the encoding)?  I tried with 1 row in test1 and still got utf-8 encoding.  I verified using the `file test.txt` command in linux.  I got this output: `> file test.txt` 
`test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: @cmjohns:Yes. Just tested again. 

data test (encoding=utf8); set sasuser.Acities; file "C:\Documents and Settings\***\Desktop\Test\encoding_test.txt" encoding='utf-8' mod; put / ' <termEntry id="' _N_ +(-1) '">' / ' <note type="TS_Status">' airport name '</note>' / ' <note type="TS_Remark"></note>' ; run;

The encoding of output txt file remains ANSI. YOu can have a try. So weird...

Comment: @mj: I'm still curious what program or method you are using to determine the encoding of the text file.  I seem to get different results from different methods.  The properties dialog of TextPad, for example, shows ANSI, but the Notepad++ program shows UTF-8.  The file command in Linux, also shows UTF-8.

Comment: Incidentally - if I open the "encoding_test.txt" file with Firefox then select View->Character Encoding, it also shows UTF-8.  The windows "Notepad" program also shows UTF-8.

Comment: If all your char are between chr(0) to chr(127), a utf8 (without BOM) text file is byte-by-byte the same as a ANSI text file.  So, some software will say it is ANSI, some say utf8.  Only when your file contain some, for example, Chinese char, the encoding in utf8 and ANSI are different.  Then, the software can distinguish which is which.